# Not getting SharePoint 2016 template

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a SharePoint 2016 empty solution using visual studio 2015, I also installed Update 2 of Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015.

Still i am not getting the 2016 solution.

Comment: Did you try https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to install Microsoft office developer as mentioned at [Office / SharePoint template missing in Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Create a new Project > below Templates > C# > Check office / Sharepoint that should be displayed as shown below.

[image]